# Tkinter not found after cx_Freeze process

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, exe, cx-freeze

I wrote the folowwing at the top of my script:

```
try:
    from Tkinter import *
    from Tkinter import messagebox
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import messagebox
else:
    print("tkinter error")
    input()
    sys.exit()
```

Running my script as .py or .pyw works without problems. But when I make and .exe out of it with cx_Freeze, the exe throws the error:

[image]

And why is that? how to solve this?

Thanks...

EDIT:
Also my setup.py:

```
import sys
import os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r"C:\Python\Python36-32\tcl\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r"C:\Python\Python36-32\tcl\tk8.6"

base = None


executables = [Executable("toolbar.py", base=base)]

packages = []
options = {
    'build_exe': {

        'packages':packages,
    },

}

setup(
    name = "Desktop Toolbar",
    options = options,
    version = "1.0",
    description = " ",
    executables = executables
)
```

Comment: Did you include `tkinter` when compiling?

Comment: @Ethan Field How do I do that? I'm not very experienced with cx_Freeze

Comment: Neither am I, but if it's stating `Module not found` I would assume this is because the module was not found.

Comment: Try following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42323533/when-using-cx-freeze-and-tkinter-i-get-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-c

Comment: @Ethan Field I have done everything needed in the link you gave. But my error is not at compiling. It's when I run the .exe file I get.

Comment: Apologies, wrong technical word. So you followed the steps given in that answer and you still have the same problems? Have you tried using a fresh `virtualenv` install and running cx_Freeze from there?

Comment: @EthanField How do you mean running cx_Freeze from virtualenv?

Comment: Create a fresh `virtualenv` (http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) with only the modules you need and your script and try to compile that with cx_Freeze (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40014823/compile-python-virtual-environment)